# List - Many to Many

Tags: list, lookup-column

Suppose you have a bunch of teams with members.

I need:
1. A list that shows each team with all of its members. 
2. A list that shows each person on a team and what team or teams they are a part of.

I have a very basic understanding of sharepoint, so any direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this in many ways. Below approach is unnormalized which makes it easy to create views

1. Create a list and name it Team. This list require only the Title field
2. Create a TeamMembers list. This list will have a User field and a lookup field to Team list

Create a View and Group by Team - This will show each team and its respective members

Create a second view and Filter it by `User Field = [Me]` - This will show all team the current user is part of